# display 10 percent of all items mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm just a beginner at mysql so in school we got task to do. It goes like this. Display / print 10% of all books from books in falling order. So i tried to use limit, but it doesn't work. What can i do? My code i've tried to use:

`select title, price from book
order by price desc
limit (select count(*)*0.1 from book);`

thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`limit` values have to be hard-coded constants. You can't use variables on them, e.g. `select ... limit @somevar` is a syntax error. You also can't use sub-queries or other dynamic values either. So you're stuck with either fetching the row count ahead of time and stuff it into the query string as a "hard-coded" value:

```
$ten_percent = get_from_database('select count(*) / 10 from book');
$sql = "SELECT .... LIMIT $ten_percent";
```

Or you simply fetch everything and then abort your loop once you've reached 10%:

```
$sql = "SELECT ....";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$fetched = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    $fetched++;
    if ($fetched >= ($total_rows / 10)) {
        break; // abort the loop at 10%
    }
    ... do stuff with $row
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time, but i need code in mysql. Is it possible to solve it in mysql?

Comment: you could build your string as dynamic sql in mysql using a stored proc, basically the same was as two line example above. ugly, but doable.

Comment: can i ask you if you can do this for me? i really would need help with this. we don't even know basics of mysql and they gave us this.

Comment: could you do this for me? plz i really need it

Comment: @poppytop Are you sure you need a pure SQL solution? Like Marc B described its ugly and generally not the best way to do it...

Comment: sorry but yes i need it in Mysql because that's my homework :(

Comment: @poppytop In that case, have a good read [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html). That and the answer Marc B posted should help you formulate your solution.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#idm47092574781424  either the above, or upgrade to at least v5.5.6